# Is it possible to make a batch file launch a separate batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, launch

I have a elevated batch file and I want it to execute a different batch file in a separate window I need to know if it is possible and how to do it. Can any one help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if you want to launch a file, say `sample.bat`, you can use

> start "Title" cmd /c sample.bat

`Title` is the title text I want to display for the new window.

You can see the details in [Documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc723564.aspx#XSLTsection124121120120)

> Enter a START command in an existing command shell, and specify CMD as the command to execute.